# How to add controllers to header file

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I am learning how to use SQLite in iOS using objective c. I referred to [this tutorial](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2013/06/ios-sqlite-crud-operations-example.html), and in the section titled "nterface file for the App Delegate - SqliteDataAppDelegate.h
" the author coded the following:

**Author's code**:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "DisplayViewController.h"

@interface SqliteDataAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController  
*navigationController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) DisplayViewController  
*displayViewController;

@end
```

Actually, in the the storyboard, I added a ViewController and I embedded a NavigationController as shown in image-1 below

**image-1**:

[image]

but I tried to ctrl+drag both of the NavigationController and the ViewController to SqliteDataAppDelegate.h file, but it is not possible.

please let me know how to add the ViewController and UINavigationController to SqliteDataAppDelegate.h file and what is UIWindow?

Comment: use `UIView`  with `XIB` than you can add programetically view into Current window , `[self.window addSubView:viewWithXIB];`

Comment: would you please tell me how to find the XIB in Xcode

Comment: @user2121 the tutorial you are following is very old one suitable for old versions of iOS and Xcode . I would prefer this tutorial over the one abouve http://www.appcoda.com/sqlite-database-ios-app-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

This's impossible. You can not connect a ViewController's subview as an outlet. Look at the sample code, there is no IBOutlet before the properties so I assume they are created by code.